# Sign Out feature MailCore 2 iOS IMAP

Tags: ios, objective-c, mailcore2, mailcore

I am using MailCore 2 iOS IMAP source to have IMAP mail access. I added mail folder list etc. features in that. I want to provide "Sign Out" feature for any imap mail that logged-in. Could anyone advise me, how to clear the existing login session and do sign out successfully?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `disconnectOperation` on your session.

Sample (Swift):

```
var op :MCOIMAPOperation = currentSession.disconnectOperation()
```

This logs out the session. You will then need to take care of your local store (deleting your session object, messages etc.). [Here's some documentation on it.](http://libmailcore.com/mailcore2/api/Classes/MCOIMAPSession.html#//api/name/disconnectOperation)

Comment: @Jeeped It does provider an answer. I can explain it more fully but to someone using Mailcore it should make perfect sense and any more detail is superfluous. I can give a more fully example if necessary but it's pretty simple - call the ```disconnectOperation``` method on your session object.

Comment: "disconnectOperation" alone doesn't do signout like operation. Can you please share the sample code snippet?

Comment: @Stella Added some more info. If that's not what you need can you explain in full what you would like the sign out to do?

Answer (score 0):

Sample code that working for me

IMAPSessionHelper.swift

```
class IMAPSessionHelper: NSObject {

   fileprivate static var privateShared: IMAPSessionHelper?
   var imapSession: MCOIMAPSession!

   class func shared() -> IMAPSessionHelper {
      guard let uwShared = privateShared else {
        privateShared = IMAPSessionHelper()
        return privateShared!
      }
      return uwShared
   }

   class func destroy() {
       privateShared = nil
   }

   private override init() {
     imapSession = MCOIMAPSession()
     imapSession.hostname = _IMAP_HOST_NAME
     imapSession.port = _IMAP_PORT
     imapSession.connectionType = .TLS
   }

   func config(with account: Account) {
     imapSession.username = account.email
     imapSession.password = account.password
   }
}
```

Logout:

```
fileprivate func logout() {
    let logout = IMAPSessionHelper.shared().imapSession.disconnectOperation()
    logout?.start({ (error) in
        if let error = error {
            logger(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        IMAPSessionHelper.destroy()
        _ = self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
    })
}
```